# Scala convert Parquet to CSV - Writer slow and resource intensive

Tags: scala, hadoop, parquet

I'm using some libraries referenced on the offical Apache Parquet page to convert Parquet files to CSV in Scala. They are written in Java - https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-compatibility

The code works, and for the most part I'm happy enough with it, except for the writeGroup code which is pretty much copypasta from the lib linked above. 
For large files (e.g. 800 MB parquet) its excruciatingly slow (over an hour), very high memory usage (Java 8 Gig, IntelliJ 2 Gig) and at times 100% CPU usage.

Does anyone understand the Parquet format well enough to have a grip on how to write writeGroup properly?

Code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.parquet.example.data.Group
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.example.GroupReadSupport
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.metadata.ParquetMetadata
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.{ParquetFileReader, ParquetReader}
import org.apache.parquet.schema.MessageType


trait ParquetConverter {

  type FilePath = String

  def convertParquetToCsv(targetDir: FilePath)(inputFile: FilePath): Try[FilePath]
}

class ParquetConverterImpl extends ParquetConverter with LazyLogging with LogSupport {

  val CSV_DELIMITER: String = ","
  val JavaNull: Null = null //scalastyle:off

  def convertParquetToCsv(targetDir: FilePath)(inputFile: FilePath): Try[FilePath] = {

    logger.info(s"Converting $inputFile to CSV")

    val hadoopConfiguration: Configuration = new Configuration(true)
    val groupReadSupport: GroupReadSupport = new GroupReadSupport

    def parquetFilePath: Try[Path] = LogTry { new Path(inputFile) }
    def footerMetaData(hadoopConfiguration: Configuration, parquetFilePath: Path): Try[ParquetMetadata] = LogTry { ParquetFileReader.readFooter(hadoopConfiguration, parquetFilePath) }
    def bufferedWriter(csvOutputFile: File): Try[BufferedWriter] = LogTry { new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvOutputFile)) }
    def parquetReader(parquetFilePath: Path, groupReadSupport: GroupReadSupport): Try[ParquetReader[Group]] = LogTry { new ParquetReader[Group](parquetFilePath, groupReadSupport) }

    def csvGroups(parquetReader: ParquetReader[Group]): Try[Stream[Group]] = LogTry { Stream.continually(parquetReader.read()).takeWhile(_ != JavaNull) }

    for {
      parquetFilePath <- parquetFilePath
      footerMetaData <- footerMetaData(hadoopConfiguration, parquetFilePath)
      schema = footerMetaData.getFileMetaData.getSchema
      _ = groupReadSupport.init(hadoopConfiguration, JavaNull, schema)
      csvOutputFile <- getOutputFilePath(targetDir, parquetFilePath)
      bufferedWriter <- bufferedWriter(csvOutputFile)
      _ <- writeInitialHeaders(schema, bufferedWriter)
      parquetReader <- parquetReader(parquetFilePath, groupReadSupport)
      csvGroups <- csvGroups(parquetReader)
      _ <- writeGroups (bufferedWriter, csvGroups, schema)
      _ <- closeReader(parquetReader)
      _ <- closeWriter(bufferedWriter)
    } yield { csvOutputFile.getAbsolutePath }
  }

  private def LogTry[A](computation: => A): Try[A] = {
    Try(computation) recoverWith {
      case e: Throwable =>
        logger.error(e.getMessage)
        Failure(e)
    }
  }

  private def writeGroups(bufferedWriter: BufferedWriter, groups: Seq[Group], schema: MessageType): Try[Unit] = {
    LogTry {
      groups.foreach(group => writeGroup(bufferedWriter, group, schema))
    }
  }

  private def closeWriter(bufferedWriter: BufferedWriter): Try[Unit] = {
    LogTry {
      bufferedWriter.close()
    }
  }

  private def closeReader(parquetReader: ParquetReader[Group]): Try[Unit] = {
    LogTry {
      parquetReader.close()
    }
  }

  private def writeInitialHeaders(schema: MessageType, bufferedWriter: BufferedWriter): Try[Unit] = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    LogTry {
      schema.getFields.asScala.foreach(fieldType => bufferedWriter.write(fieldType.getName + CSV_DELIMITER))
      bufferedWriter.write("\n")
    }
  }
```

There are a lot of problems with writeGroup below. It's copypasta Java and not remotely functional. 
What I discovered while writing this was that groupToWrite.getValueToString(j, 0) will treat no value as null, catch it and wrap it in a runtime exception. But no value is perfectly valid if there are optional values in the schema, hence the particularly awful catch RuntimeException.

I suspect its all this exception catching and especially being wrapped in the LogTry function that's causing such issues with scaling (for files less that 100 meg it works fine).

```
  private def writeGroup(bufferedWriter: BufferedWriter, groupToWrite: Group, schema: MessageType): Unit = {

    for (j <- 0 to schema.getFieldCount) {
      if (j > 0) bufferedWriter.write(CSV_DELIMITER) //IOException

      try {
        val valueToString = groupToWrite.getValueToString(j, 0) //RuntimeException
        bufferedWriter.write(valueToString) //IOException
      } catch {
        case _: RuntimeException =>
          bufferedWriter.write(""    )
      }
    }
    bufferedWriter.write('\n')
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) and build flame graphs to see what is happening underhood?

Comment: My suggestion would be to rewrite the code for both ``writeGroups``and ``writeGroup`` methods so they can be parallelized for better CPU usage (n cores instead of a single one). By doing this, the ``writeGroup`` method wouldn't have to deal with IO.

Comment: I've given up and binned the code at this point, we discovered a library called eel which basically reduces all that chaos above to
```
  val source = new ParquetSource(path)
  val sink = CsvSink(new Path(getLocalTempDir + "\\output.csv"))

  source.toDataStream().to(sink)
``` 
It took two minutes to create a 1.5Gig file